# Installing ADT plugin in Eclipse for Android development

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

when I tried to install the ADT to eclipse (indigo) the following error came up:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138547364 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138547364)
Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138547364 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138547364) requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.0.100.20110804-1717]' but it could not be found
```

What does this mean? How can I fix this?

I have the 64 bit versions of eclipse and jdk, and I tried to install the ADT through the Eclipse Marketplace, same error came up... and I tried to install the eclipse classic... an error came up that said it couldn't find the shared libraries...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It seems that you have to [run Eclipse as administrator](http://msmvps.com/blogs/rfennell/archive/2011/07/18/solution-to-missing-requirement-shared-profile-1-0-0-1308118925849-error-when-installation-tee-sp1-on-eclipse-indigo.aspx).

Comment: I don't say this often, but OMG!

Comment: I tried to install GWT SDK before changing to run  as administrator in Win 8.1 and it blue screened on me each time I tried. I then stepped through to install each individual item and received the above error. All works fine now that I have changed to run as administrator. Thank you, Glyn.

Answer (score 5):

It's an Eclipse bug, see:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350645

You shouldn't need to be administrator to install additional plugins...

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove the ADT repo (Window->Preferences->Install/Updates->Available Software Sites)
2. Add Indigo repo ("http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo")
3. Run updates
4. Add ADT repo again and install

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it was driving me nuts!!!  Tries everything listed on here but nothing and couple of other ideas from other sites.  Finally figured out since I was on $%# &^$% VISTA that I had to move my Eclipse folder out of c:\program files to users.  That fixed it.  Thanks to all who had ideas as I could not have figured it out without the other help.