# Which software sites should I have in Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: eclipse, installation, eclipse-indigo

I just installed Eclipse Indigo (Service Release 1).  For some reason my "Available Software Sites" list is empty.  Why is this?  What sites should I have in the list?  Everything I've seen online suggests that there are a number of defaults that should be present.

ETA: Running as administrator (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027876/installing-the-android-adt-plugin-for-eclipse)) seems to have made sites show up.

Comment: From where exactly did you download it? What link did you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per edit and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027876/installing-the-android-adt-plugin-for-eclipse), it turns out I needed to run as administrator to show the available sites.

Answer (score 2):

primary update site is http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/

Please check this out: Window -> Preferences ->Install/Update -> Available Software sites

Make sure that requested sites are checked